# Insert new sheet without using PHPspreadsheet or PHPexcel

Tags: php, excel, web, spreadsheet, server-side

Hi I've seen the exporting of data to excel using PHP in this link https://www.codexworld.com/export-data-to-excel-in-php/ and I was wondering how can I insert a new sheet? All I can see is by using PHPspreadsheet/excel but I dont want to recode the implementation of data. Huge thanks in advance!